# separate between multiple PHP integers to use one of them or all of them

Tags: php, integer

What If I wanted to separate between 2 or 3 integers, so that the function chooses one, two, or three out of them, how do I do that?
Example at the top of a PHP page..

```
page_require_level(1);
```

Thus, only the user with level 1 will be allowed to view the page, but what if I wanted to say that only those with level 1 and 2 are allowed, or 1 and 3 only, or 1, 2 and 3 together .. so how do I write it?
This is the function I am using

```
  /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Find user level
  /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
  function find_by_userLevel($user_level)
  {
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_level = '{$db->escape($user_level)}' LIMIT 1 ";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    return($db->num_rows($result) === 0 ? true : false);
  }
  /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Function for checking which user level has access to the page
  /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
   function page_require_level($require_user_level){
     global $session;
     $current_user = current_user();
     $user_level = find_by_userLevel($current_user['user_level']);
     //if user not login
     if (!$session->isUserLoggedIn(true)):
            $session->msg('d','Sign n plz');
            redirect('index.php', false);

      //checking logged in User level and Require level is equal to
     elseif($current_user['user_level'] != (int)$require_user_level):

              $session->msg("d", "U don't have to view this");

            redirect('home.php', false);
      else:
            return true;
        endif;

     }
```

I tried to type at the top of the page

```
page_require_level(1);
page_require_level(2);
```

then it blocked all users even the users with the level 1 and 2
but if I only typed that

```
page_require_level(1);
```

It works fine, But I need to give the permission to view to two levels or even all the three levels.

also I tried to remove (int) from the line

```
//checking logged in User level and Require level is equal to
     elseif($current_user['user_level'] != (int)$require_user_level):
```

but it is the same.

Comment: `user_level = ` could swap to `user_level in($placeholders)`. Pass an array rather than the integer. Use array for `in` comparison. You also should use prepared statements and parameterize the query. `page_require_level([1, 3]);` then `$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($user_levels), '?'));` and then bind `$user_levels` in (note I renamed `$user_level` to `$user_levels`)...If `$db` were a PDO connection I would write this out but mysqli is too finicky.

Comment: The `if` statement logic is incorrect. Your function returns true or false, you then try to compare that to...an integer? A few logical flaws with this.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a good case for a [variadic function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list): https://3v4l.org/hBVTm. Personally I think this is also a good usage of [backed enums](https://3v4l.org/CnOrP), too.